# Lotus Notes: display fields values in different rows in column

Tags: field, lotus-notes, rows

I have a number field called `Days` and an editable names field called `Names` ( which allows multiple values ).

Let say that `Days=1` and `Names=Mike/Rock, Tom/Rock, Dean/Rock`.

I want to display them in a column view like this:

```
    1
    Mike
    Tom
    Dean
```

I tried it with `@NewLine`, but no luck for me.

I also created a computed (hidden) field `test` with the following formula as default value:

```
@Text(Days)+@NewLine+@Implode(@Name([CN];Names);@NewLine)
```

It seems to be the wanted form for me, but when I just put `test` in a column default value, it shows nothing.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your `test` field to `@text(days):Names`. This should create a multi-value field (as opposed to a single string which your test formula produces).

Then, set the multi-value separator of the [column style](http://notes.helsinki.fi/help/help8_designer.nsf//Main?OpenFrameSet) to Newline, and adjust the number of rows to match the expected number of values.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did add: @Text(Days):@Name([CN];Names) in the test field, but the view column is still empty. I add 5 at the number of rows, and multi-value separator is NewLine.

Comment: Did you change the number of rows setting on the view? I do not have a Notes client at hand, so I'm afraid I cannot verify my claims.

Comment: I did add 5 (lines) at Height - Rows.

Comment: Now it appears smth like this: 1 Mike ( on the first line ) , Tom ( 2nd line ) and so on.

Comment: Seems like the first element of the name list is concatenated rather than appended. You can try it out by setting column formula to a test value, for example `"A":"B":"C"` should produce three lines.

Comment: I think your Names field is not really multi-value. If the data was added before you checked the 'allow multi-values' box in the field properties, it will really be a single value. You can check this by looking at document properties and examining the field value. If it is shown as a single quoted string, it is just a single value and you will need to re-save it in order to convert to multi values.

Answer (score 0):

In a view we get only one row for one document. Multiple values are therefore shown in one row only with multi value separator.
Eclipse view may perhaps help.